# Creating Salesforce Custom Formula Field - (Error Incorrect Parameter Type)

Tags: salesforce, formulas, salesforce-communities

I am creating a formula for a commission field that has multiple calculations depending on criteria.  I am currently getting an error that says (Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'AND()'. Expected Boolean, received Number).  How should I modify the formula to fix this?

IF(AND(Order__r.New_Amount_Outstanding__c = 0,Order__r.RecordTypeId="Bespoke Item",ISPICKVAL( Payment_type__c , 'Deposit'), Date__c >= DATE(2017,04,01)),(Order__r.Amount_RollUp__c) *1.2/100,IF(AND(Order__r.RecordTypeId="Bespoke Item",ISPICKVAL( Payment_type__c , 'Deposit'), Date__c < DATE(2017,04,01),(Order__r.New_New_Net__c)  *1.2/100),IF(Order__r.RecordTypeId<>"Bespoke Item",(Order__r.New_New_Net__c  *1.2/100), NULL)))

It essentially consists of 3 scenarios broken out:

IF(AND(Order__r.New_Amount_Outstanding__c = 0,Order__r.RecordTypeId="Bespoke Item",ISPICKVAL( Payment_type__c , 'Deposit'), Date__c >= DATE(2017,04,01)),(Order__r.Amount_RollUp__c) *1.2/100,

IF(AND(Order__r.RecordTypeId="Bespoke Item",ISPICKVAL( Payment_type__c , 'Deposit'), Date__c < DATE(2017,04,01),(Order__r.New_New_Net__c)  *1.2/100),

IF(Order__r.RecordTypeId<>"Bespoke Item",(Order__r.New_New_Net__c  *1.2/100),

NULL)))

Answer (score 1):

You have a misplaced ")". When you indent the formula, it becomes obvious:

```
IF(
  AND(
    Order__r.New_Amount_Outstanding__c = 0,
    Order__r.RecordTypeId="Bespoke Item",
    ISPICKVAL( Payment_type__c , 'Deposit'), 
    Date__c >= DATE(2017,04,01)
  ),
  (Order__r.Amount_RollUp__c) *1.2/100,
  IF(
    AND(
      Order__r.RecordTypeId="Bespoke Item",
      ISPICKVAL( Payment_type__c , 'Deposit'), 
      Date__c < DATE(2017,04,01),
      (Order__r.New_New_Net__c) *1.2/100),
      IF(Order__r.RecordTypeId<>"Bespoke Item",
        (Order__r.New_New_Net__*1.2/100), 
        NULL
      )
   )
)
```

Should be:

```
IF(
  /*Test this Argument*/
  AND(
    Order__r.New_Amount_Outstanding__c = 0,
    Order__r.RecordTypeId="Bespoke Item",
    ISPICKVAL( Payment_type__c , 'Deposit'), 
    Date__c >= DATE(2017,04,01)
  ),
  /* If True */
  (Order__r.Amount_RollUp__c) *1.2/100,
  /* If False */
  IF(
    /* Test this Argument */
    AND(
      Order__r.RecordTypeId="Bespoke Item",
      ISPICKVAL( Payment_type__c , 'Deposit'), 
      Date__c < DATE(2017,04,01)
    ),
    /* If True */
    (Order__r.New_New_Net__c) *1.2/100),
    /* If False*/
    IF(
       /* Test this Argument */
       Order__r.RecordTypeId<>"Bespoke Item",
       /* If True */
       (Order__r.New_New_Net__*1.2/100), 
       /* If False */
       NULL
    )
  )
)
```

Also will Order__r.RecordTypeId="Bespoke Item" ever evaluate to TRUE? I think it will be an Id.